# Asterisk automatic installation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, chef, asterisk, automation

I recently started a project which I need to automate the installation of Asterisk servers for my customers in AWS infrastructure. Customers already own AWS infrastructure.

I was thinking the following approach:

a) **AMI image**:

- Install Asterisk EC2 instance and create an image (Account A).
- Move this image from Account A to customer account (Account B) and then configure accordingly. This may be challenging as not sure if I can transfer AMI image across different accounts.

b) **Installation script**:

Create a shell script based on the following:

http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FOP/Installing+FreePBX+12+on+Ubuntu+Server+14.04+LTS

c) **Chef**:

Use Chef server and have a bootup script for EC2 instances to install Chef client and then get the Asterisk recipe.

d) **Docker installation**

Use Docker containers and simplify installation, this will require install docker and then deploy the container.

Any suggestion/feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick one? The 4, are roughly speaking, mutually incompatible (I suppose you could use Chef to install/start the docker containers or something). B is probably right out as strictly worse than the others but the rest are all fine depending on your existing workflow and tooling.